# Load data from paramiko into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, paramiko

I have the following

```
import paramiko
import pandas as pd
cert = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("./pem.pem")
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname="server",username="user",pkey=cert)

filee = client.open_sftp().open("head.log")
```

How do I (most efficient) turn `filee` into a pandas dataframe/numpy-array?

Is it by

```
for line in filee:
    df.append(line)
```

or can you do it as a one-liner?

Answer (score 2):

It defenitely depends on what your log file looks like, but if it is structured as a `csv` file you can use:

```
with client.open_sftp().open("head.log") as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
```